# Processing objects won't move on x-axis using while loop & if statement

Tags: key, processing, move

I am working on a space ship Processing project where when the key is pressed, the bullet moves on the x axis and keeps going right from where it left off up until it reaches the width of the screen. Once it reaches the width of the screen the bullet goes back to its original position in front of the space ship again. In other words, gives a feel of those old arcade space shooting games.

How I tried to do this was with a while and if statement in KeyPressed loop. When the position = width the bullet is created again (back in front of ship); however the bullet never moves.

I am really new to processing so I don't think I understand how their while and if statements work.
[image]

```
//bullet
int bulletP1X = mouseX+248;
int bulletP1Y =mouseY+100; 
int bulletP2X = mouseX+207;
int bulletP2Y = mouseY+100;
int bulletRextX = mouseX+215;
int bulletRextY = mouseY+95;
int bulletT1X = mouseX+240;
int bulletT1Y = mouseY+100;
int bulletT2X = mouseX+215;
int bulletT2Y = mouseY+100;

void setup(){

size(1300,810);  

}

void draw(){
background(0,0,0);
fill(121,17,17);
strokeWeight(1);
stroke(0,0,0);

triangle(mouseX+20,mouseY+50,mouseX+20,mouseY+150,mouseX+200,mouseY+100);
fill(255,255,210);
triangle(mouseX+150,mouseY+87,mouseX+150,mouseY+113,mouseX+200,mouseY+100);

//Left wing of Space Ship
beginShape();
stroke(255,255,255);
fill(121,17,17);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+50);
vertex(mouseX+40,mouseY+40);
vertex(mouseX+200,mouseY+95);
vertex(mouseX+200,mouseY+105);
endShape();

//Right wing of Space Ship
beginShape();
stroke(255,255,255);
fill(121,17,17);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+150);
vertex(mouseX+40,mouseY+160);
vertex(mouseX+200,mouseY+105);
vertex(mouseX+200,mouseY+100);
endShape();

//Inside white banner of Space Ship (top)
beginShape();
stroke(255,255,255);
fill(255,255,255);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+65);
vertex(mouseX+55,mouseY+85);
vertex(mouseX+150,mouseY+90);
vertex(mouseX+150,mouseY+100);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+100);
endShape();

//Inside white banner of Space Ship (bottom)
beginShape();
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+135);
vertex(mouseX+55,mouseY+115);
vertex(mouseX+150,mouseY+112);
vertex(mouseX+150,mouseY+100);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+100);
endShape();

//White back of ship behind the cockpit
beginShape();
fill(255,255,255);
vertex(mouseX+5,mouseY+80);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+65);
vertex(mouseX+20,mouseY+135);
vertex(mouseX+5,mouseY+115);  
endShape();

fill(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX+30,mouseY+100,30,20);
ellipse(mouseX+60,mouseY+70,10,10);
ellipse(mouseX+60,mouseY+130,10,10);
stroke(0,0,0);

//square shapes inside ship
fill(255,255,255);
stroke(0,0,0);
rect(mouseX+100,mouseY+95,50,10);
rect(mouseX+105,mouseY+98,40,4);

//line design inside white part of Space Ship
line(mouseX+20,mouseY+100,mouseX+60,mouseY+70);
line(mouseX+30,mouseY+110,mouseX+60,mouseY+130);

//bullet
bulletP1X = mouseX+248;
bulletP1Y =mouseY+100; 
bulletP2X = mouseX+207;
bulletP2Y = mouseY+100;
bulletRextX = mouseX+215;
bulletRextY = mouseY+95;
bulletT1X = mouseX+240;
bulletT1Y = mouseY+100;
bulletT2X = mouseX+215;
bulletT2Y = mouseY+100;

  fill(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(255,0,0);  
  //side tips
  point(bulletP1X,bulletP1Y);  
  point(bulletP2X,bulletP2Y);

  //bullet body
  strokeWeight(1);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(bulletRextX,bulletRextY,24,10);

  //TWO_PI IS FULL CIRCLE
  //PI + HALF_PI == 1.5 PI == -0.5 PI
  //TAU + HALF_PI == TWO_PI + HALF_PI == 2.5 PI == 0.5 PI

  //round ends of bullet
  arc(bulletT1X,bulletT1Y,12,12,-HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
  arc(bulletT2X,bulletT2Y,13,12,radians(90),radians(270));

}
```

This is the part of my coding that should move the bullet on the x axis but it doesn't.

```
void keyPressed(){


background(0,0,0);
fill(255,0,0); 

while (bulletP1X != width || bulletP1X < width || bulletP2X != width || bulletP2X < width
      || bulletRextX != width || bulletRextX < width || bulletT1X != width || bulletT1X < width || bulletT2X != width || bulletT2X < width){   


  fill(255,255,255);
  stroke(0,0,0);

  bulletP1X +=25;
  bulletP2X+=25;
  bulletRextX +=25;
  bulletT1X+=25;
  bulletT2X+=25;

  fill(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(255,0,0);  
  //side tips
  point(bulletP1X,bulletP1Y);  
  point(bulletP2X,bulletP2Y);

  //bullet body
  strokeWeight(1);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(bulletRextX,bulletRextY,24,10);

  //round ends of bullet
  arc(bulletT1X,bulletT1Y,12,12,-HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
  arc(bulletT2X,bulletT2Y,13,12,radians(90),radians(270));

}

if (bulletP1X == width || bulletP1X > width || bulletP2X == width || bulletP2X > width
      || bulletRextX == width || bulletRextX > width || bulletT1X == width || bulletT1X > width || bulletT2X == width || bulletT2X > width){

   fill(255,255,255);
   stroke(0,0,0);

  //bullet
  bulletP1X = mouseX+248;
  bulletP1Y =mouseY+100; 
  bulletP2X = mouseX+207;
  bulletP2Y = mouseY+100;
  bulletRextX = mouseX+215;
  bulletRextY = mouseY+95;
  bulletT1X = mouseX+240;
  bulletT1Y = mouseY+100;
  bulletT2X = mouseX+215;
  bulletT2Y = mouseY+100;           


  fill(255,0,0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(255,0,0);  
  //side tips
  point(bulletP1X,bulletP1Y);  
  point(bulletP2X,bulletP2Y);

  //bullet body
  strokeWeight(1);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(bulletRextX,bulletRextY,24,10);

  //round ends of bullet
  arc(bulletT1X,bulletT1Y,12,12,-HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
  arc(bulletT2X,bulletT2Y,13,12,radians(90),radians(270));

      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you some readings:

http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8087/what-are-setup-and-draw

http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8085/i-display-images-in-sequence-but-i-see-only-the-last-one-why

http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8082/from-several-variables-to-arrays

http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8081/from-several-arrays-to-classes

The function `keyPressed()` as it's siblings `mousePressed()`, `mouseClicked()`, etc... Are not "loops" as you said, they are callBack functions, meaning they are called once every time the event happens, so when a `key` is pressed, the code inside `keyPressed()` is executed once.

`draw()` is a infinite loop that tries to run itself 60 times each second. The commands inside it are executed in order (top -> bottom) and the result is finally rendered at the end of each cycle.

This is why, usually, is not good idea to draw inside callback functions. Use it to set states or flags to drive things in `draw()`. Also a while loop will hold execution, preventing draw to reach the end of the cycle and render the drawings...

There is also a built in variable `keyPressed`that you can use in `draw()` to check if some key is being pressed.

Also whenever you got a lot of `someVar1`, `someVar2`... You should consider using an array, and if you got some arrays holding related stuff, like `xPos[]`, `yPos[]`, `xSpeed[]` and so on classes becomes really handy. It seems to be difficult but they actually make things easier right after you learn them.

Also to keep things in a desired range (xPos) the modulo `%` operator is very helpful.

Here a simple way of making "bullet" travels when any key is pressed, being reset after reaching the edge:

```java
int initial_x = 50;
int x_pos = initial_x;
void setup() {  
    size(300, 300); 
    background(0);      

} 

void draw() { 
    background(0);
    if(keyPressed){
        x_pos+=3;
        if(x_pos >= width){
            x_pos = initial_x;
            }
        }  
    ellipse(x_pos, 100, 10, 10);
}
```

A side note, you might consider wrapping all code to draw the ship in a function (or even better a class) so you can keep your `draw()` tide. Something like:

```java
void spaceShip(int x, int y){
    //code to draw ship at (x,y)
}
```

and in draw you would have

```java
spaceShip(mouseX, mouseY);
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for all the examples and information over how to use keyPressed and mousePressed. I was playing with it and just realized that you can use keyPressed inside draw which definitely made something react so I now know that fact. However, I really appreciate all the explanation. I will look over all your links. Thank you again for helping me. I just started processing and what you see above is me using keypressed and mousepressed for the first time as you can see